# How to restrict a function variable based on another variable?

Tags: typescript-generics

I am trying to get my head around some Typescript generics. Is it possible to use generics to limit one attribute of a function call based on the input of another?
For example, say that I have a function that takes some array, but also takes another data structure. Is it possible to limit that data structure to only allow inputs that was made in the first array?
I have made a shaved down example here:

```
interface MyTestInterface{ //This isn't really imparative, I just wanted to limit the function
  var1: string;
  var2: boolean;
  var3: number;
}
interface MyTestLink<T>{
  from: T;
  to: T;
}
function isThisPossible<I extends MyTestInterface, KI extends keyof I>(
  vars: KI[], //I can only enter the keys of the first interface, which is fine
  links: [MyTestLink<any>] //What do I replace any with here, to limit the input?
){
  //Do something with vars!
}
function testFunction(){
  isThisPossible(
    ["var1", "var2"],
    [{from: "var1", to: "var2"}] //I would like a compiler error if either of these values are not in the vars array
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say that `vars` is subset of `KI`:

```
function isThisPossible<I extends MyTestInterface, KI extends keyof I, Vars extends readonly KI[] = readonly KI[]>(
  vars: Vars, //I can only enter the keys of the first interface, which is fine
  links: [MyTestLink<Vars[number]>]
){
  //Do something with vars!
}
function testFunction(){
  isThisPossible(
    ["var1", "var2"],
    [{from: "var1", to: "var2"}] // not error :)
  );
  isThisPossible(
    ["var1", "var2"],
    [{from: "nonexist", to: "woah"}] // error :)
  );
}
```